# Big amounts of data in Amazon RDS

Tags: php, mysql, database, amazon-rds

Currently I'm trying to store a big amount of e-mails (100M+) in mysql in Amazon RDS. I've made a seperate emails_bodies table but it's getting way to big.

With around 40k e-mails the table size just got over 1GB, using Amazon RDS. The original (e-mail) files are saved on the Amazon S3 and the bodies (text-only) are just in the DB for searching. With higher user-numbers (which easily counts over 100M emails) I would use TB's of mysql storage.

```
CREATE TABLE `emails` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `accounts_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ehash` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `subject` text NOT NULL,
  `body` longtext NOT NULL,
  `html` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `size` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `last_updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ehash` (`ehash`),
  KEY `accounts_id` (`accounts_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE `bodies` (
  `bodies_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bodies_emails_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `bodies_body` longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bodies_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `bodies_emails_id` (`bodies_emails_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: is that a typo or is bodies_id listed twice in the table 'bodies'?

Comment: It was a type. Thanks for the notification ;)

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Am I taking you right that it's table size being your concern?

Comment: If there are any tips / solutions to still provide a (reliable) search without using that much mysql space.

Comment: @YourCommonSense thats correct, with ~100M e-mails (which can grow easily to 250M+ eventually) I will be using TB's of mysql storage (Even the big Amazon RDS is maxed out at 3TB).

Comment: It appears that the table definitions look ok, but you will have problems loading that much data into longtext data types. Perhaps SQL is not the answer - you could load the emails table and have a PHP function which searches the files containing the body text?

Answer (score 0):

According to my calculations, each body consumes 25K in average. That's pretty fair amount for the email body. Though you can reduce that amount if extract only text part out of multipart body, if your only intention is search. I am sure that average size will be reduced to mere 1k or less.

Comment: I just reset and am importing emails again. I am using strip_tags() and a trim() (both PHP) on the body. So it's almost only text (with a couple linebreaks / whitespace within. I'm getting around 6kb text only (though only ~2k rows atm because of reset). Does this has something to do with that I'm using longtext?

Comment: I think I've found the problem; almost all e-mails still contain (alot) whitespace. Is there any good php function which will not online trim (before and after any text) but also remove white lines, tabs and more than 1 (white)space(s)?